# Match multiple patterns in same line

Tags: javascript, regex

I have something like

```
var string = "<h1>Hi {{name|there}}</h1>
<p>This is a message<br>
</p>
<p>Hello hello</p>"
```

I want to find all {{...}} tags and replace it with the first attribute (left-hand side of |) with a corresponding value. If that value doesn't exist, I want to replace the tag with the 'fallback' on the right-hand side (in this case the string 'there')

So far I've tried something like below, but it doesn't get the groups

```
/{{(.+)|(.+)}}/
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Show us what you have tried ?

Comment: Do you mean there can be `{{name|there}}` (=> `name`), or `{{|there}}` (=> `there`) or `{{there}}` (=> `there`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like that:

```js
var string = "<h1>Hi {{name|there}}</h1> <p>This is a message<br></p><p>Hello hello</p>";

// If the variable exists
console.log(parse(string, {name: "Tony"}));

// If the variable is not set
console.log(parse(string, {potato: "Tony"}));

function parse(str, values){
  str = str.replace(/\{\{(.*)\|(.*)\}\}/g,function(arg, match1, match2){
    var data = match1.split("|");
    var variable = match1;
    var fallback = match2;
    var replace = fallback;

    if(typeof(values[variable]) != "undefined"){
      replace = values[variable];
    }
    return replace;
  });
  return str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your input can look like `{{name|there}}` (=> `name`), or `{{|there}}` (=> `there`) or `{{there}}` (=> `there`), you may use the following approach:

```js
var string = `<h1>Hi {{name|there}}</h1>
<p>This is a {{|message}}<br>
</p>
<p>Hello {{hello}}</p>`;
var rx = /{{(.*?)(?:\|(.*?))?}}/g;
console.log(string.replace(rx, function(m,g1,g2) {
  return g1 ? g1 : g2;
}));
```

*Details*:

- `{{`  - literal `{{` text
- `(.*?)` - Group 1 capturing any 0+ chars other than linebreak symbols as few as possible up to the first
- `(?:\|(.*?))?` - optional sequence of

  - `\|` - literal `|`
  - `(.*?)` - Group 2 capturing any 0+ chars other than linebreak symbols as few as possible up to the first
- `}}` - literal `}}` text.

In the replacement, Group 1 is checked first, and if it is not empty its contents are returned. Else, Group 2 contents are returned.

Answer (score 1):

You might do as follows;

```js
var str = "<h1>Hi {{name|there}}</h1>",
   val1 = "muçaços",
   val2 = undefined,
   str1 = str.replace(/\{\{(\w+)\|(\w+)\}\}/,(m,p1,p2) => val1||p2),
   str2 = str.replace(/\{\{(\w+)\|(\w+)\}\}/,(m,p1,p2) => val2||p2);
console.log(str1);
console.log(str2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should escape all these characters: { } |

```
string.match(/\{\{(.+)\|(.+)\}\}/)
```